# using select in winsock2

Tags: select, winsock

I'm trying to get select to work right and it seems to be returning 1 even when there is nothing to be read on the socket. So I end up calling recv and it blocks because nothing is there to read.

Also annoying is the fact that with winsock it is necessary to call FD_SET each time select is called, which isn't consistent with standard implementations.

Are there any other weird quirks I need to be aware of?

Comment: Show us your code. Without it we can tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it but I cannot determine what exactly the cause of the problem was. I do know that it is very relevant that `FD_SET` must be used to re-set the set for each `select()` call. According to the documentation, after calling `select` it fills in the sets which are ready for read/write/etc.

Moral of the story today is: read the documentation.